# Remove entire lines form text file based on URL form 12 colum

Tags: linux

I have a file abc.txt in that file having 29 records In these records we need to **remove** some of the lines which are having the url based on the URL http://163.172.47.140:55555/

For example:

```
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://163.172.47.140:55555/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
```

Comment: Have you tried with a text editor,  eg. vi ?

Answer (score 1):

With **`sed`** command:

Sample `input.txt`:

```
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://163.172.47.140:55555/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://192.172.45.130:55550/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://163.172.47.140:55555/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
```

---

```
sed -i '/http:\/\/163\.172\.47\.140:55555\//d' input.txt
```

- `-i` - edit file *inplace*
- `d` - delete records matching a certain pattern

The final `input.txt` contents:

```
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://192.172.45.130:55550/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -vF 'http://163.172.47.140:55555/' input
```

- `-vF str` - all lines that don't contain *str*

Comment: I want to remove the entire line with this http://163.172.47.140:55555/

Answer (score 1):

Inputfile

```
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://163.172.47.140:55555/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://195.175.45.130:55550/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://163.172.47.140:55555/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
```

Below command delete the lines which contains "http://163.172.47.140:55555"

Command:

```
 awk '!/http:\/\/163.172.47.140:55555/{print $0}' inputfile
```

output

```
-       163.12372.473.1440  35010   2018-01-18 01:03:13 +0000       POST http://195.175.45.130:55550/?oip=163.172.47.140 HTTP/1.1   200     147  -est_useragent  -       -       test_refe    test_useragent  -       -       test_referer    text/json       323
```

Comment: cool and readable ... or even `awk '!/http:\/\/163.172.47.140:55555/'`